# How can i secure non-asp files in a classic asp environment

Tags: security, asp-classic

I have a folder in which all asp files are protected by including validate.asp (which presents a login if the session is not validated and ends the response, otherwise it allows the page to display.

How can I protect non-asp content?

The Site is running under Windows 2003 Server with IIS 6.0

Comment: What OS and IIS version is this site running under?

Comment: @Oded: Windows 2003 Server/IIS6 [Added to question]

Answer (score 0):

@My Other Me: check out [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/)

> ISAPI_Rewrite is a powerful URL manipulation engine based on regular expressions. It acts mostly like Apache's mod_Rewrite, but is designed specifically for Microsoft's Internet Information Server (IIS). ISAPI_Rewrite is an ISAPI filter written in pure C/C++ so it is extremely fast. ISAPI_Rewrite gives you the freedom to go beyond the standard URL schemes and develop your own scheme.

Alternatively, you can also check out [IIS Password](http://www.iistools.com/en/iispassword.html)

> IISPassword password protects web sites that are hosted on Microsoft IIS, without using system user accounts. IISPassword protects complete web sites, subfolders or even certain files or file types. When trying to access a password protected object, the user is asked to log in through a dialog box ..

ISAPI Rewrite has a lite version and IISPassword has a trial version, so you can try out both for free to see if they could suit your needs.

Comment: Pardon my lack of imagination, but how would I use ISAPI Rewrite to do this. Would I redirect all traffic to a central asp file and in that check for validity and then serve up the file from the asp file?

Comment: @My Other Me: That's the gist of it, yes. :-)